# Obtain all of the columns from sql server using php in one command?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Is there a way to get all the data from a sql server table. 
What i am trying to acheive is i have a sql table with 5 columns. They will have x amount of entries, but all of them will have x amount. So for example five columns i have are A,B,C,D,E. All of them will have 10 entries or 20 entries.

Now i know how to run the query for one of them

```
    $serverName = "server"; //serverName\instanceName
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"db", "UID"=>"u/n", "PWD"=>"pass");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    $sql = "SELECT A FROM Table";
    $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    if ($query === false){  
        echo "Could not link to SQL Server";
    }
    $i = 0;  
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
    {   
        $A[$i] = "$row[A]";
        $i++;
    }        
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($query);
    sqlsrv_close( $conn );
```

So in this code I get the values of column A and they are stored in $A array of length $i. My question is can I (and if yes how), to do this for all the column at once without copying the code. I know

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table";
```

But what to do after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't something like this work?

```
$serverName = "server"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"db", "UID"=>"u/n", "PWD"=>"pass");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table";  //change this to select * like you would in SQL
$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if ($query === false){  
    echo "Could not link to SQL Server";
}
$i = 0;  
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
{   
    $A[$i] = "$row[A]";
    $B[$i] = "$row[B]";
    $C[$i] = "$row[C]";  //add rest of the columns similarly
    $i++;
}        
sqlsrv_free_stmt($query);
sqlsrv_close( $conn );
```

Comment: @Seth No worries! We all have been there. :) If you could please close this question by marking the answer as `accepted`. That would be great! Thanks!